# How can I use the DevExpress WinForms TextEdit as a password entry (with asterisks)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

According to http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/editors/textEdit.xml one can use the Developer Express TextEdit control to input a password and hide the characters.  Can anyone explain to me how to do this?  It seems like it should be really simple.

Comment: Use TextEdit.Properties.PasswordChar = '*'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [RepositoryItemTextEdit.PasswordChar Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemTextEdit_PasswordChartopic)

> The TextEdit has a `Properties.PasswordChar` property, which is empty by default. By >setting some char there (for example, *), you will enable the functionality you require.

Password mode allows you to mask the editor's text. You can activate password mode in two ways:

- Set the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property to `true`. The editor's text will be masked as follows:
- Set the `PasswordChar` property to `any valid character`. This character will be used to mask the editor's text.

  For instance, if the `PasswordChar` property is set to `"*"`, an editor will work as you want to do.

**Note:** The `PasswordChar` property is ignored if the `RepositoryItemMemoEdit.UseSystemPasswordChar` property is set to `true`.

Pragmatically you can set it as:


```
 TextEdit.Properties.PasswordChar = '*'
```

And From GUI go to Properties section and then further look for the `Properties` there you will get the `PasswordChar` property, Set it to valid character as per documentation. e.g. `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Set `PasswordChar` property of `TextBox` to the character which should be visible in the text box instead of the real text.

For example:

```
textBox.PasswordChar = '*';
```

Comment: I don't have a PasswordChar.  Maybe because I'm using an old version of DevExpress (8.2).  Perhaps it's something that was added later.  I'll have to investigate.

Comment: Oh, I missunderstood your question. I thought you were talking about Visual Studio Express and I was talking about the regular .NET TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with the regular TextBox control if you set the TextBox.**UseSystemPasswordChar** to true. This setting will also cause the TextBox control to display a tooltip warning if your CapsLock is on, just like in the Windows Login screen.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use a regular TextBox.  I want to use a DevExpress control.